# how to combine group of columns below another group of columns in R

Tags: r

All I want to do do is combine columns[1:3] with columns[4:6].

The final product would just have 3 long columns with col[4] below col[1], col[5] below col[2], etc.

All the solutions I see depend on ID columns that are non existent in my data.  I looked at gather(),stack(), melt().  I just want to simply cut the last 3 columns and paste them below the first 3 columns,

Comment: yes, `melt` , `pivot_longer` and `reshape` ca do the work as needed: eg `reshape(df, matrix(1:6,2,byrow = true), dir = "long")`

Comment: You could add an `id`, do the transformation, then remove it. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: try somethin like `reshape(df, matrix(1:6,2,byrow = true), dir = "long")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rename the columns to match first you can use the `rbind` function to paste the last three columns below the first three columns.

```
names(df) <- rep(names(df)[1:3], 2)
df <- rbind(df[,1:3], df[,4:6])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the columns all contain the same class (i.e. integer), you can simply use the `rbind()` function to bind columns [4:6] under columns [1:3].

If they have different formats, you can define a new dataset with combined columns:

```
new.data = data.frame("First"=c(data[,1],data[,4]),
                      "Second"=c(data[,2],data[,5]),
                      "Third"=c(data[,3],data[,6]))
```

With `rbind()` you can just add the columns below, as in this example:

```
> dta = matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),6),ncol=6,byrow=T)
> print(dta)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
> rbind(dta[,1:3],dta[,4:6])
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    1    2    3
 [3,]    1    2    3
 [4,]    1    2    3
 [5,]    1    2    3
 [6,]    1    2    3
 [7,]    4    5    6
 [8,]    4    5    6
 [9,]    4    5    6
[10,]    4    5    6
[11,]    4    5    6
[12,]    4    5    6
```

Comment: Edited the post to give an example. But mark that this will only work if the object class of all elements is the same. If you have character columns and numeric columns, use the `data.frame()` function to manually compose the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your data is like below, you could use `reshape` from base R:

```
a <- head(cbind(iris[1:3], iris[1:3]))
a
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
1          5.1         3.5          1.4          5.1         3.5          1.4
2          4.9         3.0          1.4          4.9         3.0          1.4
3          4.7         3.2          1.3          4.7         3.2          1.3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5          4.6         3.1          1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4          5.0         3.6          1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7          5.4         3.9          1.7
```

The code to use:

```
reshape(a, matrix(names(a), 3), dir="long")

    time Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length id
1.1    1          5.1         3.5          1.4  1
2.1    1          4.9         3.0          1.4  2
3.1    1          4.7         3.2          1.3  3
4.1    1          4.6         3.1          1.5  4
5.1    1          5.0         3.6          1.4  5
6.1    1          5.4         3.9          1.7  6
1.2    2          5.1         3.5          1.4  1
2.2    2          4.9         3.0          1.4  2
3.2    2          4.7         3.2          1.3  3
4.2    2          4.6         3.1          1.5  4
5.2    2          5.0         3.6          1.4  5
6.2    2          5.4         3.9          1.7  6
```